# Adjusting the transparency for the Shield UI ASP.NET chart background image

Tags: asp.net, shieldui

I have two related Shield UI ASP.NET Charts. I intend to provide different information for my visitors. In addition, I want to use the chart’s data area for placing some banners. The problem is, that for users who have logged in, or who have higher scores I need the images to be less visible than to the newcomers. I researched the online documentation but there are no additional properties to be set. There is only:

```
{
     chartAreaBackgroundImage: 'image url'
}
```

Is there a way to set transparency for instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transparency for Shield UI ASP.NET can’t be adjusted. In case the  number of banners is fixed, you may retouch your images so that there is one of an appropriate opacity for the corresponding group of users. You may use an array:

```
var imageData = DataImageURLs[UserLevel].values,
```

accessing the desired image by the user’s level of privilege or other number.

Than place the appropriate image:

```
            dataSeries: [{
                seriesType: 'line',
                collectionAlias: 'Information',
                data: detailData
            }],
```